# Memoir pagenote (endnote) id's all coming out the same

Tags: memoir, expansion, pagenote

I am creating a document using the memoir package and specifically memoir's endnote facility (which is called pagenote to avoid naming conflicts). The document, when complete, will have an entry for each day of the year. I am automating the generation of the date strings (in two different formats) using the texdate package.

For the ease of the reader I want the tag (or id) for each endnote to be a date string (e.g., Jan 1) rather than just a sequential integer. The problem is that (it seems) the date strings are not being evaluated until the page of endnotes gets written, with the result that all the endnote entries are tagged with the same date.

How can I fix this?

```
% pagenoteMWE.tex
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

% begin preamble       *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{texdate}

% The following is required in the preamble for using memoir's pagenote (endnote) capability
\makepagenote

\renewcommand*{\idtextinnotes}[1]{#1\space}  % remove square brackets surrounding note id
\renewcommand{\prenoteinnotes}{\par\noindent\hangindent0.6in}
\renewcommand\prenotetext{\hskip-3.52pt}

% Create named date formats for texdate package
\nameddateformat{monthandday}{B e}   % January 5
\nameddateformat{monandday}{b e}     % Jan 5

% Custom command for using memoir's \pagenote command
\newcommand{\mypagenote}[2]{\small\pagenote[\hbox to 0.6in{#1\hfill}]{\small#2}}
% end preamble    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *

\begin{document} 
\title{A Passage for Each Day of the Year}
\date{\strut}
\maketitle 

\initdate{2024}{12}{31}    % initializes texdate's date

\vspace{-80pt}

%-- Jan01 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\advancebydays{1} \begin{center} \Large \printfdate{monthandday}\par \end{center} \par\noindent
I do not doubt she had a choice pleasure in exhibiting what she called her
self-command, and her firmness, and her strength of mind, and her common sense
and the whole diabolical catalogue of her unamiable qualities, on such an
occasion.
\mypagenote{\small\printfdate{monandday}}{David Copperfield recalling his
interaction with the vile Miss Murdstone upon returning from school to his home
upon the death of his mother.}
\bigskip
%-- Jan02 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\advancebydays{1} \begin{center} \Large \printfdate{monthandday}\par \end{center} \par\noindent
In the hierarchy of post-Civil War times was Mrs.\ Hamilton Fish, whose husband
became Secretary of State in Grant's Cabinet; she belonged to what was called
``the Faubourg St.\ Germain set'' of New York--families entrenched since
Colonial days in wealth and civic eminence, who could afford to live in
tarnished magnificence on outmoded Second Avenue, while ``swells'' eddied like
moths toward the luster of Fifth Avenue.
\mypagenote{\small\printfdate{monandday}}{Dixon Wecter, \emph{The Saga of
American Society: A Record of Social Aspiration, 1607-1937}, New York: Charles
Scribner's Sons, 1937.}
\bigskip

\printpagenotes
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How committed are you to `texdate`?

Comment: @cfr - Not committed, but it would be nice if the alternative code was reasonably compact.

Comment: Just I looked at this before and didn't see an easy way (for me) to answer with `texdate`. I assumed somebody else would have provided a solution meanwhile. But I think it could be done with a different mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the values inside the endnote, so the `\printfdate` command will pick up the right data.

```
% pagenoteMWE.tex
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

% begin preamble       *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{texdate}

% The following is required in the preamble for using memoir's pagenote (endnote) capability
\makepagenote

\renewcommand*{\idtextinnotes}[1]{#1\space}  % remove square brackets surrounding note id
\renewcommand{\prenoteinnotes}{\par\noindent\hangindent0.6in}
\renewcommand\prenotetext{\hskip-3.52pt}

% Create named date formats for texdate package
\nameddateformat{monthandday}{B\ e}   % January 5
\nameddateformat{monandday}{b\ e}     % Jan 5

% Custom command for using memoir's \pagenote command
\newcommand{\mypagenote}[2]{%
  \small
  \expanded{\noexpand\pagenote[\noexpand\dateinnote{\setdate\unexpanded{#1}}]}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\dateinnote}[1]{\makebox[0.6in][l]{#1}}
\makeatletter
\let\texdmon\texd@mon\let\texdrdom\texd@rdom
\newcommand{\setdate}{\texdmon=\the\texd@mon\texdrdom=\the\texd@rdom\space}
\makeatother
% end preamble    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *

\begin{document}

\title{A Passage for Each Day of the Year}
\date{\strut}
\maketitle 

\initdate{2024}{12}{31}    % initializes texdate's date

\vspace{-80pt}

%-- Jan01 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\advancebydays{1} \begin{center} \Large \printfdate{monthandday}\par \end{center} \par\noindent
I do not doubt she had a choice pleasure in exhibiting what she called her
self-command, and her firmness, and her strength of mind, and her common sense
and the whole diabolical catalogue of her unamiable qualities, on such an
occasion.
\mypagenote{\printfdate{monandday}}{David Copperfield recalling his
interaction with the vile Miss Murdstone upon returning from school to his home
upon the death of his mother.}
\bigskip
%-- Jan02 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\advancebydays{1} \begin{center} \Large \printfdate{monthandday}\par \end{center} \par\noindent
In the hierarchy of post-Civil War times was Mrs.\ Hamilton Fish, whose husband
became Secretary of State in Grant's Cabinet; she belonged to what was called
``the Faubourg St.\ Germain set'' of New York--families entrenched since
Colonial days in wealth and civic eminence, who could afford to live in
tarnished magnificence on outmoded Second Avenue, while ``swells'' eddied like
moths toward the luster of Fifth Avenue.
\mypagenote{\printfdate{monandday}}{Dixon Wecter, \emph{The Saga of
American Society: A Record of Social Aspiration, 1607-1937}, New York: Charles
Scribner's Sons, 1937.}
\bigskip

\advancebydays{120}
X\mypagenote{\printfdate{monandday}}{Something}

\advancebydays{120}
X\mypagenote{\printfdate{monandday}}{Something}

\printpagenotes
\end{document}
```

Note the change in the format instructions, `B\ e` and `b\ e` so a space will appear between month and day.

[image]

Comment: So you could also have said `\newcommand{\setdate}{\texdmon=\the\texdmon\texdrdom=\the\texdrdom\space}`?

Comment: @egreg - Thank you. This was exactly what I was hoping for!

Answer (score 4):

If you use `datenumber`, it is more straightforward to handle the expansion issues (at least for me). The downside is the lack of an out-of-the-box macro for producing short month names. Here I modify the approach used for long month names, taking some short cuts which make the code specific to this usage and to English. More flexible facilities would be straightforward to implement, but require a bit more code.

Two macros are provided for use in the document:

- `\passage[<integer>]` starts a new entry. If the optional argument is used, the date will be `<integer>` days after (or before) the previous date. If `<integer>` is omitted, a value of `1` is used i.e. the following day.

  - This creates the heading and sets the date counter appropriately, so it should be straightforward to adjust the format for the whole document in one place.
- `\mypagenote{<text>}` creates a page note using the current date for the label and `<text>` for the body.

  - If desired, an optional argument could be provided to override the default content of the label. Based on your description, it seemed unlikely this would be necessary, but it would be easy to add.

`expl3` is used because it reduces expansion problems to a question of syntax. If you're not familiar with it, it will look alien. But it is a very friendly alien once you get past the green-bug-eyed-monster look.

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714287/ addaswyd o gwestiwn Paul Dulaney: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/714093/
% BEGIN preamble       *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *

\usepackage{datenumber}

% The following is required in the preamble for using memoir's pagenote (endnote) capability
\makepagenote

\renewcommand*{\idtextinnotes}[1]{#1\space}  % remove square brackets surrounding note id
\renewcommand{\prenoteinnotes}{\par\noindent\hangindent0.6in}
\renewcommand\prenotetext{\hskip-3.52pt}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \pedy_mypagenote:nn
{
  \small
  \pagenote [ \hbox to 0.6in {\setdatebynumber { #1 }  \myshortmonthname { \thedatemonth } ~ \thedateday   \hfill } ]{ \small #2 }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \pedy_mypagenote:nn { en }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \mypagenote #1
{
  \pedy_mypagenote:en { \thedatenumber } { #1 }
}
% modified from datenumberenglish.ldf
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \pedy_shortmonthnameenglish:n 
{
  \int_case:nn { #1 }
  {
    { 1 } { Jan }
    { 2 } { Feb }
    { 3 } { Mar }
    { 4 } { Apr }
    { 5 } { May }
    { 6 } { Jun }
    { 7 } { Jul }
    { 8 } { Aug }
    { 9 } { Sep }
    { 10 } { Oct }
    { 11 } { Nov }
    { 12 } { Dec }
  }
}
\cs_new_eq:NN \myshortmonthname \pedy_shortmonthnameenglish:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\NewDocumentCommand \passage { O {1} }
{%
  \addtocounter{datenumber}{#1}%
  \setdatebynumber{\thedatenumber}%
  \begin{center} 
    \Large 
    \datemonthname{} \thedateday{}
  \end{center} 
  \par\noindent
}
% END preamble    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *

\begin{document} 
\title{A Passage for Each Day of the Year}
\date{\strut}
\maketitle 

\setdatenumber{2024}{12}{31}

\vspace{-80pt}

%-- Jan01 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\passage % or \passage[<n>] to advance by <n> days
I do not doubt she had a choice pleasure in exhibiting what she called her
self-command, and her firmness, and her strength of mind, and her common sense
and the whole diabolical catalogue of her unamiable qualities, on such an
occasion.
\mypagenote{%
  David Copperfield recalling his
  interaction with the vile Miss Murdstone upon returning from school to his home
  upon the death of his mother.%
}
\bigskip

%-- Jan02 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\passage
In the hierarchy of post-Civil War times was Mrs.\ Hamilton Fish, whose husband
became Secretary of State in Grant's Cabinet; she belonged to what was called
``the Faubourg St.\ Germain set'' of New York--families entrenched since
Colonial days in wealth and civic eminence, who could afford to live in
tarnished magnificence on outmoded Second Avenue, while ``swells'' eddied like
moths toward the luster of Fifth Avenue.
\mypagenote{%
  Dixon Wecter, \emph{The Saga of
    American Society: A Record of Social Aspiration, 1607-1937}, New York: Charles
  Scribner's Sons, 1937.%
}
\bigskip

%-- Jan10
\passage[8]
Something later.
\mypagenote{%
  Test skipping dates works.%
}

\printpagenotes
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code deserved an image.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! I never expected you to say my code deserved anything positive!

Comment: @cfr -  Thank you for a very creative effort, and for introducing me to expl3.